# Cannot list folder items or run files on shared folder Virtualbox with Ubuntu installed

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I cannot list the items of a shared folder, on my Virtualbox with Ubuntu Server installed. I installed Guest Additions and shared my Windows folder like visualized here:
[image]

After adding the folder I mounted the folder on Ubuntu using vboxsf. Everything went fine so far. Now, I can access the folder and the subfolders by refering to it (using the "cd" command), but I cannot list anything or run any file. Everytime I try to run a command, it stops doing anything (without showing any error or whatsoever), see screenshot below:
[image]
Same for listening the folders, it just stops doing anything:
[image]

the windows folder is the shared folder with my files hosted on my Windows desktop. The strange part is, on my Virtualbox with CentOS installed everything works just fine.

Anyone who has a solution for this?

Comment: The shared folder appears to be in "Users". Are you sure the VM has access to that folder? Showing the full path of the share and your mount command may help.

Comment: what do you mean with it appears to be in "users"? I used vboxsf to mount the www shared folder to a specific path, in my case that's /var/www/windows. In Virtualbox I gave it full access. And I can access the subfolders as long as I know their specific name, I cannot list the content of the folders.

Comment: Your picture shows "/Us...ard/documents" as the Windows folder that is being shared. I don't see what that has to do with "www".

Comment: I'm sorry, that's just a picture I got from the internet. It was just to show you how I shared the folder with the virtual machine. I shared the C:/wamp/www folder on the Windows client, which is aliased as windows in the www folder on the Ubuntu virtual machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is fixed. I tried to reïnstall Guest Additions, but this time I was sure that I installed the software as "root" user. Now everything works fine!

Comment: How didi you do to install the software as root?